# Align a <a > inside a td in css

Tags: html, css

I have an img as an `<a>` tag in html inside a `<td>` form and I'm trying to center align it;
My structure is:

```
<td><span class="AlertaOK"><a title="Processado"></a></span></td>
```

I tried center-align, vertical-align like this:

```
<td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">
```

My (part of) css:

```
{
background: url(../images/sprite-icons.png) -297px -149px no-repeat center !important;
color: transparent !important;
height: 15px !important;
color: transparent !important;
display: block !important;
width: 17px !important;
float: right !important;
border: 15px !important;
text-indent: -9000px !important;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
margin-left: 1px;
line-height: 100%;
}
```

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: do you have a width for your `td`?

Comment: @j08691 Thanks for the edition ! I was kind in a hurry !

Comment: @DanielA.White no, I don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `<a>` as big as the `<td>` and then use `background-position` as in @BhojendraNepal's answer, or you can give arbitrary dimensions to the `<a>`, and center it with

```
    display : block;
line-height : 100%;
     margin : 0 auto;
```

as shown in the following snippet:

```css
td {
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

a{
    background-image : url('http://newbleep.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/stackoverflow.png');
         width : 128px;
        height : 128px;
       display : block;
   line-height : 100%;
        margin : 0 auto;
        border : 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>    
    <td><span class="AlertaOK"><a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Processado"></a></span></td>
    <td><div>Spacer</div></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><div>Spacer</div></td>
    <td><div>Spacer</div></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Edited my answer with the <a> css

Comment: Stop using float (especially if you want to **center** something). And stop using **!important** like that :O

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using background image, you need to center that background with `background-position: center` or you may use:

```
.AlertaOK a{
   background: url(path.jpg) no-repeat center;
}
```

Comment: OP has stated as using image in `a` tag.... and there's no such `img` tag meaning OP is using background image for that...

Comment: Yes I am, but now the img is not shown, using `center`

Comment: have you defined the width and height for that..?

Comment: Edited the question with the css ! I forgot to mention that the img is taken like a sprite, from a bigger img